# Format ldap result into json

Tags: python, json, formatting, ldap

I need to convert ldap result into json. i have been trying for hours and I did not find any solution.

```py
search_filter = "CN=My Name"
attrs = ['givenName', 'sn', 'thumbnail_pic', 'phone', 'mail']
result = connect.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_filter, attrs)
```

I have this output:

```py
('CN=My Name,OU=City,OU=Company,DC=com,DC=lan', {'sn': [b'Name'], 'givenName': [b'My'], 'phone': [b'+111 111 111 111'], 'mail': [b'My.Name@company.com'], 'thumbnail_pic': [b'binary data of picture']})
```

And I want to convert it into this pretty json

```
[
            {
                "first_name": "My",
                "last_name": "Name",
                "picture": "binary data of picture",
                "phone_number": "+111 111 111 111",
                "email": "My.Name@company.com",
            }
]
```

I am desperate for help since I think I tried almost everything... Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson). This library can handle bytes strings very well.

```sh
pip3 install simplejson
```

Sample usage:

```py
import simplejson

ldap_result = ('CN=My Name,OU=City,OU=Company,DC=com,DC=lan', {'sn': [b'Name'], 'givenName': [b'My'], 'phone': [b'+111 111 111 111'], 'mail': [b'My.Name@company.com'], 'thumbnail_pic': [b'binary data of picture']})

print(simplejson.dumps(ldap_result[0][1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for including the installation instructions and sample usage as part of your answer. Often, newer contributors just suggest a library—which isn't very useful if it doesn't also show how that library can solve a problem. Keep up the good work!